# I am training Yolov5 on OID dataset and I'm getting these errors, "Caught KeyError in DataLoader worker process 0" and "KeyError: 'copy_paste'"

Tags: python, yolov5

So this is my error, I am using the OID dataset for training using the YOLOV5 model. As a reference, I'm using this article: https://blog.paperspace.com/train-yolov5-custom-data/.
I am getting stuck at the training part, please help.

```
 [Epoch   gpu_mem       box       obj       cls    labels  img_size
  0% 0/664 \[00:00<?, ?it/s\]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "train.py", line 667, in <module>
    main(opt)
  File "train.py", line 562, in main
    train(opt.hyp, opt, device, callbacks)
  File "train.py", line 323, in train
    for i, (imgs, targets, paths, _) in pbar:  

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tqdm/std.py", line 1195, in __iter__
    for obj in iterable:
  File "/content/yolov5/utils/datasets.py", line 160, in __iter__
    yield next(self.iterator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 530, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1224, in _next_data
    return self._process_data(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1250, in _process_data
    data.reraise()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/_utils.py", line 457, in reraise
    raise exception
KeyError: Caught KeyError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 287, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 49, in fetch
    data = \[self.dataset\[idx\] for idx in possibly_batched_index\]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 49, in <listcomp>
    data = \[self.dataset\[idx\] for idx in possibly_batched_index\]
  File "/content/yolov5/utils/datasets.py", line 589, in __getitem__
    img, labels = self.load_mosaic(index)
  File "/content/yolov5/utils/datasets.py", line 725, in load_mosaic
    img4, labels4, segments4 = copy_paste(img4, labels4, segments4, p=self.hyp\['copy_paste'\])
KeyError: 'copy_paste'][1]
```

Comment: You did not tell what problem you are facing...

Answer (score 1):

I get this problem and get resolved by add this line in data/hyp.scratch.yaml file.

copy_paste: 0.0 # segment copy-paste (probability)

Hope this solved for you.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're using an old version of yolov5. Kindly update your code by `git pull` from main repo or download it as zip file.

If this does not solve your problem, kindly provide more info like your train command and your use case.